# Dygraph dynamic update

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am new to the Dygraphs library and I need help with plotting dynamic data using Dygraph. I have seen this example in Dygraph

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [];
  var t = new Date();

  var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div_g"), data, {
    drawPoints: true,
    showRoller: true,
    valueRange: [0.0, 1.2],
    labels: ['Time', 'Random']
  });
  // It sucks that these things aren't objects, and we need to store state in window.
  window.intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var x = new Date(); // current time
    var y = Math.random();
    data.push([x, y]);
    g.updateOptions({
      'file': data
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_g" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
<p>This test is modeled after a
  <a href="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-update&amp;theme=default">highcharts
test</a>. New points should appear once per second. Try zooming and panning over to the right edge to watch them show up.</p>
```

and this is exactly I need.

But, I can see that there is no scrolling option (*please correct me if I am wrong*). Therefore, my question is how to simulate the scroll feature so that the old chart points are moved to the left.

*Can it be done by programmatically panning the chart?*. Or by some other better way.

Please suggest !!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the x-axis range using the [`dateWindow`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow) option. If you want to smoothly animate the chart range, I'd suggest calling that with `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: thanks for replying ... sorry for the trouble... but I need something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/YAC2L/).. here the old data is moving to the left and also highcharts provide a scrollbar to see the old data... how to acheive the same using dygraphs ...

Comment: @danvk, can you provide some sample code or reference link will helps, even am also searching for same.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by removing the same number of points that you "push" into the plot to "shift out" from the left side of the plot, like the example you show.

Fortunately there is already a function to do that - `shift()`

Now to use it all you have to do is call `shift` before you `push` new data -

```js
data.shift();
data.push([x, y]);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24217079)

Comment: @tsturzl ``` .....old chart points are moved to the left.```. That is what shift does. Please run it yourself and check it. If it still does not answer the question, i will remove it.

Comment: It's not whether I think it does or doesn't answer the question, it's just ambiguous. It's a low quality answer that could be edited to include a description which could make this a feasible answer. Explaining your answer is part of providing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is already scrolling feature provided in the Dygraphs. Instead of using .shift() method, you can use the range selector feature as provided in the below demo.

> http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector

And you can fix the display range to the first half of the total range. So it will move the points to left and will be a live update and also you will not be removing any points from the graph.